# Manually adding p value and bracket to a more complicated violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have gene counts I would like to plot, coming from two groups. Within each group, I have males and females.

Using the following code, I am able to produce what I want, which is all data points in each group (CTRL vs SA) plotted, but with violins showing distributions by sex:

```
ACTB <- read.csv("ACTB_normcounts.csv")

# Create the violin plot
pdf("ACTB_group_sex.pdf")
p <- ggplot(ACTB, aes(x = Group, y = Count, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.05), color = "#2e2e2e", size = 4) +
  labs(title = "ACTB",
       x = "Group",
       y = "Normalized Count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Male" = "#3375ff", "Female" = "#ff5a50")) +
  theme_minimal()
p +  stat_summary(fun = "mean",
                  geom = "crossbar", 
                  width = 0.2,
                  colour = "#2e2e2e",
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Now I have p value for expression difference (calculated previously) for CTRL vs SA (both sexes pooled per group) that I would like to manually add to the plot along with a bracket. However, the following code stops producing a plot all together. Can someone help me correct it?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

ACTB <- read.csv("ACTB_normcounts.csv")

# Create the violin plot
pdf("ACTB_group_sex.pdf")
p <- ggplot(ACTB, aes(x = Group, y = Count, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.05), color = "#2e2e2e", size = 4) +
  labs(title = "ACTB",
       x = "Group",
       y = "Normalized Count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Male" = "#3375ff", "Female" = "#ff5a50")) +
  theme_minimal()

p 

# Make a p-value table
df_p_val <- data.frame(
  group1 = "CTRL",
  group2 = "SA",
  p.adj = 0.02)

df_p_val <- df_p_val %>%
  mutate(y.position = c(46500))

p +  stat_pvalue_manual(df_p_val, label = "p.adj") + 
     stat_summary(fun = "mean",
               geom = "crossbar", 
               width = 0.2,
               colour = "#2e2e2e",
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))

dev.off()
```

Here is a snippet of the data used:

Count:25101.60891, 26949.29768, 20027.67572, 27971.35216, 25167.80826, 34819.22693, 25123.1769, 22323.66741

Group: SA, SA, CTRL, CTRL,SA, SA, CTRL, CTRL

Sex: Male, Male, Male, Male, Female, Female, Female, Female,

[image]

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) on how to provide data to responders so they can best answer your question. Please do not include pictures of dataframes only.